# Is there a built-in equivalent to C#'s Enumerable.Single()?

Tags: python

in C#, if you have an enumerable and try to call [.Single()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb155325(v=vs.100).aspx) on it, it will throw an error if it does not have exactly one element in it.

Is there something similar built-in to Python for this?

```
if len(iterable) == 0 or len(iterable) > 1:
    raise Error("...")
return iterable[0]
```

Comment: Can you explain why you need it to raise an Exception? Maybe you want to use an [assertion](https://docs.python.org/3.5/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-assert-statement) like assert(len(iterable) == 1)?

Comment: What's the use case for this? I'm having a hard time thinking of a good one.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Not a built in method, but there is an idiomatic way to achieve the same goal:

`(value,) = iterable` raises `ValueError` if `iterable` doesn't contain exactly one element.

The single element will be stored in `value` so your example could be simplified to:

```
(value,) = iterable
return value
```

The unpacking is a feature of the [assignment operator](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/simple_stmts.html#assignment-statements).

> If the target list is a comma-separated list of targets: The object must be an iterable with the same number of items as there are targets in the target list, and the items are assigned, from left to right, to the corresponding targets.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more and/or link to docs on what's happening with the unpacking?

Comment: Sure! Updated the answer. When the target of the assignment operator (=) is a comma separated list, every element from the iterable will be assigned to each item in the target list. A ValueError is raised if the number of items in target doesn't match the number of items in the iterable.

Comment: Thanks! I'm still a bit confused about the `,` in `(value,)`. Playing around, `(value)` will cause `value == iterable`. What does the `,` do?

Comment: Oh, and the parentheses aren't needed, some people (including me) use them for readability since a single comma is easily missed.

Comment: Try `a,b = [1,2]` (which is identical to `a,b, = [1,2]`). Hope that will make things clearer.

Comment: So the `,` tells python to unpack values, but since only one variable name is provided, only one value is attempted to unpack?

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there is though you can simplify it to:

```
def single(iterable):
    if len(iterable) != 1:
        raise Error("...")
    return iterable[0]
```